# What is the plane of the net in volleyball?

Tags: rules, volleyball

If a volleyball hits the top tape of the net but no part is over the net, is that considered crossing the plane?

Answer (score 2):

No - even if the net is pushed quite far due to the speed of the ball, it's still not considered crossing the plane. If, however, this happens and then the ball moves over the top of the net such that the net begins to spring back to it's resting position at the centreline, the ball immediately breaks the vertical plane when any part of the ball passes the net, at which time it can be played.